# Integrating Facebook Login for Business in an Existing Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I'm currently facing a challenge with integrating Facebook Login for Business in an existing web application that has been running for several years. Due to recent changes, we are now required to use Facebook Login for Business, which is impacting all our live clients who are unable to log in via Facebook and access the services they pay for.

The core issue is that our existing application does not support configuring the updates needed for Facebook Login for Business. It appears that these updates can only be applied by creating a new application. However, creating a new application is not trivial or ideal for our situation. Additionally, the new login method that works on new applications is not shown under the products tab to be added to our existing application.

**Specific Challenges:**

1. **Inability to Update Existing Application:** We are unable to configure the necessary updates on our existing application to accommodate Facebook Login for Business.
2. **Creating a New Application:** The option to create a new application is not feasible due to the scale of our operations and the impact it would have on our current user base.
3. **Product Integration Issue:** The Facebook Login for Business product is not available to be added under the products tab in our existing application's settings.

**Questions:**

1. How can we integrate Facebook Login for Business into our existing application without having to create a new one?
2. Is there a way to enable the Facebook Login for Business product for an existing application?
3. Are there any known workarounds or steps that I might be missing to update our existing application to support Facebook Login for Business?

- **Thorough Documentation Review:** We have extensively reviewed the available documentation provided by Facebook for tech providers but haven't found a solution for updating existing applications as opposed to creating new ones.
- **Exploring Facebook Developer Settings:** We have attempted to navigate through our current application settings in the Facebook Developer console, looking for options to enable the Facebook Login for Business product, but this option seems to be unavailable.
- **Seeking Assistance from Facebook Support:**

Comment: What features are available, depends on the app type - and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app#app-type does not make it sound like the type could be changed later on. (_"Later, when you are more familiar with our products and APIs, refer to our app types document to determine which app type is best suited for your app, **then create a new app and choose an appropriate type**."_) Trying to contact support and ask if they could change the app type for you, is probably you best option.

Comment: The issue es that we have the App type set as business and approved as tech providers. Its an app we have had for years, but the new options are nowhere to be found, just in the newly created apps. Its an issue of course because we have live clients relying on these applications that now cant be integrated (but can use if the keep the integration). I tried to open a ticket, but have no category for these and they refer to the dev community forums. Thanks very much for trying!

Comment: _"Its an app we have had for years"_ - app types are a relatively new thing, so I suppose you can't have chosen the business type when you created this, but it has been automatically set by Facebook when they "migrated" stuff to this new system(?) - and maybe something was not set a 100% correct while that happened. I'd still try and contact support, and ask them to look into this.

Comment: I will try. Maybe the app wasnt type business and was migrated and type changed automatically but at the same time not giving the whole options? who knows. So you might be right, the app might have been for years, but not on business type. What im sure is that we are certified as tech provider which was also a requirement. If you have any tip about how to get support with meta Im all ears. I tried their forums and so far you are the only person with an answer. Much appreciated, seriously.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create/ is probably your best bet to get someone to look into this.